# Join List of strings trailing values don't require delimiters if the right most value is null

Tags: c#, list

What im trying to achieve, but cant get my head around is if i have a list of strings say:

```
{"test","","data","","123","44"}
```

this should be joined by a character:

```
test::data::123:44
```

but if the list at the end is empty dont delimiter it

```
{"test","","data","","",""}
```

should be:

```
test::data

{"test","","","","",""}
```

should be:

```
test

{"test","","","","","44"}
```

should be:

```
test::::44
```

however the list can be of varying lengths which adds another level of complexity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String.Join method that ignores empty strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325995/string-join-method-that-ignores-empty-strings)

Comment: That's not what i'm looking for, because i don't want it to ignore empty strings i want it to only ignore trailing empty strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just exclude the trailing empty elements from the list `Count` and then [`Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx) the remaining using [`Take`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
List<string> input = ...;
int count = input.Count;
while (count > 0 && string.IsNullOrEmpty(input[count - 1]))
    count--;
var output = string.Join(":", input.Take(count));
```

Using the `List<T>` specific [`FindLastIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzs5503w(v=vs.110).aspx) method, it can be reduced to the following "one liner":

```
var output = string.Join(":", 
    input.Take(input.FindLastIndex(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) + 1));
```

Comment: @Amit Right. But the question is tagged `list`, not `linq`. Which reminded me that there is a specific list method for that, so thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

First, with your array:

```
test =  test.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
```

where "test" is your array.

then:

```
string.Join("::", test);
```

EDIT:

If you're getting your array of strings by splitting another string, consider the following:

```
string[] strs = myString.split(someDelimeter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  var obj = {"test","","data","","123","44"};
  var count = obj.Count;

  for (var i = count - 1; i > -1; i--)
  {
    if (obj[i]==String.Empty) {
      obj.RemoveAt(i);
    }
    else break;
  }

  var arr = obj.Split(new char[] { ','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

  var output = arr.Join(":", arr);
```

Comment: my input isnt a JSON value its just a list of strings, its for EDIFACT D96a where trailing values don't require delimiters if the right most value is null

Answer (score 1):

Start by identifying the last element you want, then slice your list and join as you normally would:

```
var lastElementIndex = strings.Select((s, index) => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? -1 : index).Max();
var prefix = strings.Take(lastElementIndex + 1);
var result = string.Join(":", prefix);
```