# Append commas only if strings are not null or empty

Tags: c#

I am creating simple webform in C#. Here I am getting full address by concatenating which works well. But let's say if I don't have `address2`, `city`, etc, then I want to skip appending commas at end of each string (e.g. if `address1` is null or empty).

```
string address1 = "Address1";
string address2 = "Address2";
string city = "City";
string country = "Country";
string postalCode = "00000";

string fullAddress = ? --> address1 + ","+ address2 +","+ city  and so on
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String.Join method that ignores empty strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325995/string-join-method-that-ignores-empty-strings)

Comment: @Hermann.Gruber Whilst incredibly similar and very much overlapping I think this question (and the subsequent answers) show that this can be done on a selection of variables and not only on an array (albeit several of the answers create an array as part of the process) making this question worthy of keeping in its own right.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

If you want to remove the empty or null string you have to filter the array used in the [`join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-8.0) method:

```
var array = new[] { address1, address2, city, country, postalCode };
string fullAddress = string.Join(",", array.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)));
```

If we make `city=""` the we have `Address1,Address2,Country,00000`

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, you made my day

Answer (score 24):

you could use [string.join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) along with a [filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) to remove the duplicated commas when one or more of the values are null or empty.

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", new string[] { address1 , address2 , city , country , postalCode }.Where(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c))));
```

Comment: Upvoted for being 5m earlier than the accepted answer and doing it all on one line like a ninja.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
string address1 = "Address1";
string address2 = "Address2";
string city = "";
string country = "Country";
string postalCode = "00000";

Func<string, string> f = s => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? string.Empty : string.Format("{0},", s);
string fullAddress = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}", f(address1), f(address2), f(city), f(country), f(postalCode)).Trim(',');
```

Comment: This is the right answer. It accounts for the variables being null.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `string.Join` to do your task. You can [run in dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2hJpHi).
Please check below code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string address1 = "Address1";
        string address2 = "Address2";
        string city = "City";
        string country = "Country";
        string postalCode = "00000";

        List<string> strArray = new List<string> { address1, address2, city, country, postalCode };

        string fullAddress = string.Join(",", strArray.Where(m=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m)).ToList());

        Console.WriteLine(fullAddress);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated my answer, it will ignore `empty` value.

Answer (score 1):

[String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you need.

```
string address1 = "Address1";
string address2 = "Address2";
string city = "City";
string country = "Country";
string postalCode = "00000";

string[] stuff = new string [] { address1, address2, city, country, postalCode };

string fulladdress = string.Join(",", stuff).Replace(",,",",");
```

Comment: Your answer does not account for null variables.

Comment: That does not remove the duplicated commas when one of the values is empty

Comment: That's because a string is a nullable type.  `string.Join` replaces null parameter values with "string.Empty" with the assumption that other code is determining null handling.  If the array itself is null, then an exception is thrown.  I'd suggest as a matter of separation of concerns, following with `string.Replace()` replacing ",," with "," would better address null values.  I Updated the answer with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all your elements in an array and join the array with the ",". In this case, the commas will be well placed, betweed your different address part.