# Concatenate strings from array in PHP ignoring blanks

Tags: php, arrays, string, concatenation

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16325995/4468423) but for PHP.  I want to concatenate an array of strings but ignore blanks.

For instance, suppose I want to build a `full_name` attribute in Laravel using `$this->title`, `$this->first_name`, and `$this->last_name`, each separated by single space.  The simplest thought I had was to put them all into an array and pass it into [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) as in below:

```php
implode(' ', [$this->title, $this->first_name, $this->last_name]);
```

However I don't know whether those values are actually going to be set or not.  And if they are set, I don't want empty strings to pollute the output with multiple spaces between non-empty elements.  Is there a built-in function or at least a simpler/shorter way to do the below?

```php
public function concatenateStringsFromArray($glue = ' ', $arrayOfStrings)
{
    $result = '';
    foreach($arrayOfStrings as $piece)
        $result .= isset($piece) ? $piece . $glue : '';
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Did you try with `trim()` function?

Comment: @unclexo i can't see how that would prevent consecutive spaces from appearing due to nulls/blanks in the middle of the array.

Comment: I can't see what your goal is. What should come out of this input array     ['a', ' b  c',null, '     ','def ']

Comment: @jspit good question -- i was assuming that provided strings would be single words without any whitespace (or at least [trimmed](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e04a7ffba8b80b934506783a7d0a161dd52eb2ef/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php)). to fail the test, strings should be not null or empty (i.e. `''`).  so your array should result in `a  b c   def ` i think.

Answer (score 2):

array_map with trim as function removes all spaces at the beginning and end of a string, not in the middle.
array_filter removes then all elements that are empty, including zero and "".

```
$arrayOfStrings = ['a', 'b    c',null, '    ','ef ','  012'];

$result = implode(' ', array_filter(array_map('trim',$arrayOfStrings)));

echo '<pre>'.$result;  //a b    c ef 012
```

I wrote everything on one line because you wanted it to be short.

Comment: produces `"a b    c ef 012"`.  this is a good substitute for unclexo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60313125/4468423) if you need to do clean up first.

Answer (score 1):

Apply `trim()` function on each array element. See the following example:

```
<?php

$arrayOfStrings = ['a', ' b c',null, ' ','def '];

echo implode(' ', array_filter($arrayOfStrings, function($element) { 
    return trim($element); 
}));
```

The code above outputs `"a  b c def "`. Notice the space after `"def "`.

**This means `trim()` function with `array_filter()` function's callback function doesn't trim space from the right side**. To address this issue, you should use `trim()` function with `array_filter()` and `array_map()` functions. Because `array_map()` function removes spaces from both sides. See the following example:

```
<?php

echo implode(' ', array_filter(array_map('trim', $arrayOfStrings)));
```

The code above outputs `"a  b c def"`

By the way thanks to @jspit for the good catch!

Comment: that works well! on @jspit's test array above, produces `"a  b c def "`.

Comment: @Erich : The result is not the same. You have to output an echo "<pre>" in advance to see all spaces!

Comment: @jspit your comment on the question i only saw `['a', ' b c',null, ' ','def ']`.  was there a space in front of the `a`?

Comment: @jspit i'm not formatting the output for an html canvas, so no need for `<pre>`

Comment: The '<pre>' only serves to make the spaces visible in the browser. However, the spaces are in the string. Do a var_dump() and also look at the number of characters. I don't know if the difference bothers you.

Comment: @jspit yes, you're right. Though I tested on command line tool.

Comment: Not that `array_filter()` will greedily remove all falsey, null, zeroish, and no-length values by default.  This answer will destroy `0` values.

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from an [example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php#117676) using `array_filter`:

```php
return implode($glue, array_filter($arrayOfStrings, function($element) { 
    return $element !== null && $element !== ''; 
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

[`array_filter()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) should do the trick.
Simply calling `implode($glue,array_filter($array))` should give you what you want, by filtering out all elements of the given array which resolve to `false` (0, null and '' among others). If you need 0 or other values which resolve to boolean false as valid values you can use a custom callback:

```
array_filter($array, function($value) { return !is_null($value) && $value !== ''; })
```